# how to solve this uncaught error in react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, vscode-debugger

I wrote a program in react typescript, but I got an error called uncaught error and I did run and debug tests and searched on google, but I am unable to solve this error, so I need help from anyone who can solve this error. here is my program

****react with typescript****

```
import { createContext, useContext, useMemo, } from "react"

type ComplexObject = {
  kind:string
}

const Context = createContext<ComplexObject | null >(null)
const useGetComplexObject=()=>{
  const object=useContext(Context)
  if(!object)
  {
    throw new Error("useGetComplexObject must be used within the parameter");
    return object
  }
}

export default function MyApp()
{
  const object  =useMemo(()=>({kind:"complex"}),[])
  return (
    
      <Context.Provider value={object}>
    <MyComponent />
      </Context.Provider>
    
  )
}

function MyComponent()
{
  const object=useGetComplexObject()
  return (
    <div>
      <p>current object : {object.kind}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I searched this uncaught error on google but I cannot find solution for this error, what I am expecting is to anyone who knows react with typescript can help me to solve this uncaught TypeError and improve this program

Comment: Wich error are you seeing? Is it the one you throw in `useGetComplexObject` or is it different one?

Comment: different one brother
<p>current object : {object.kind}</p>
this statement has error.

Comment: That still does not answer the question of which error you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use try catch block in MyComponent function, where it will catch the uncaught error, refer this:

```
 function MyComponent() {
  try {
    const object = useGetComplexObject()
    return (
      <div>
        <p>current object : {object.kind}</p>
      </div>
    )
  } catch (error) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Error: {error.message}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It will give you specific error you are occurring.
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: sorry brother still the program has error at this line
  <p>Error: {error.message}</p>

Answer (score 0):

Change your useGetComplexObject code like bellow.

```js
const useGetComplexObject = () => {
  try {
    const object = useContext(Context)
    return object
  } catch (error: any) {
      throw new Error("useGetComplexObject must be used within the parameter");
  }
}
```

hope this will help to fix your code error.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, Your code has an error.

```
if(!object) {
    throw new Error("useGetComplexObject must be used within the parameter");
    return object
}
```

You can't `return` after `throw new Error`. When throw the error your code never reaches the return.

The above C.HA code is a better one. Or alternatively you can use like this

```
if(!object) {
    throw new Error("useGetComplexObject must be used within the parameter");
}

return object
```